# SQL - display N/A if the rundate is after a specific date

Tags: sql, string

this is my first time posting. I am trying to display "N/A" when the the date I selected to let the query run is after a specific date, otherwise I do want a calculated number, but I keep receiving error messages. Can someone help me with this?

```
                CASE When a.run_date > a.street_day
                        THEN convert(varchar(10),pre_order_forecast) as pre_order_forecast 
                        pre_order_forecast = 'N/A'
                ELSE (CASE
                      WHEN datediff(DAY, fcst.forecast_creation_day, NVL(a.street_day)) BETWEEN 0 AND 7
                          THEN fcst_qty_wk0
                      END) 
          
                END AS pre_order_forecast
```

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Also you should post your errors **as text, not as image** to help you to resolve them. It is hard to guess, what error you see.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, a CASE expression is along the lines of

```
> CASE
>    WHEN condition test 1 THEN value/calculation
>    WHEN condition test 2 THEN value/calculation
>    ...
>    ELSE value/calculation END
```

It goes through the WHEN condition tests in sequence, until one is true; then that value/calculation is used (it's like a series of IF THEN ELSE expressions).

Writing these quickly becomes second nature imo, but to get started, you can

- Start by writing `CASE`
- On the next line, write `WHEN`, some spaces, and then `THEN`
- Fill in the thing to check whether true after the WHEN, and what the result would be if it was true after the THEN
- Repeat with the next line etc
- Add an 'ELSE' for when none of the checks are true.

In your case, I'm guessing you want something like

```
CASE WHEN a.run_date > a.street_day
         THEN convert(varchar(10),pre_order_forecast) 
     WHEN datediff(DAY, fcst.forecast_creation_day, NVL(a.street_day)) BETWEEN 0 AND 7
         THEN fcst_qty_wk0
     ELSE 'N/A'
     END AS pre_order_forecast
```

The exact syntax and fields depend on your database.

Note that in the second WHEN, you may need to also convert `fcst_qty_wk0` to varchar to match the other outputs.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much! I want it to display "N/A" when  a.run_date > a.street_day, Else it shall display datediff(DAY, fcst.forecast_creation_day, NVL(a.street_day)) BETWEEN 0 AND 7
         THEN fcst_qty_wk0

Comment: You have the logic there in what you're saying - then putting it in code is just ordering the WHENs and THENs e.g., your SQL should be something like `CASE WHEN a.run_date > a.street_day THEN 'N/A' WHEN datediff(DAY, fcst.forecast_creation_day, NVL(a.street_day)) BETWEEN 0 AND 7 THEN fcst_qty_wk0 ELSE NULL END`

Comment: Thank you so much!